# Draw a bitmap picture on IOS based on a set of RGB data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bitmap

I'd like to draw a bimap picture on IOS platform based on a set of RGB data but I got some problems when referring to this official web: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101

The biggest problem here for me is that The tutorial drew a bitmap picture on **MAC OS** while not on **IOS**.

SO, I added a subview to the view and intended to draw the bitmap picture on the subview.

```
UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 355, 384, 288)];
[self drawBitmap:384 andPixelshigh:288];
[self.view addSubview:imgview];
```

The *drawBitmap* function is a self-written function used to draw the bitmap following the tutorial.

```
- (void)drawBitmap:(NSInteger)pixelsWide andPixelshigh:     (NSInteger)pixelsHigh{
CGRect myBoundingBox;
CGContextRef myBitmapContext;
CGImageRef myImage;

myBoundingBox = CGRectMake (33, 366, 384, 288);
myBitmapContext = [self MyCreateBitmapContext:pixelsWide andPixelsHigh:pixelsHigh];
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (100, 100, 200, 100 ));
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (100, 100, 100, 200 ));
myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (myBitmapContext);
CGContextDrawImage(myBitmapContext, myBoundingBox, myImage);
char *bitmapData = CGBitmapContextGetData(myBitmapContext);
CGContextRelease (myBitmapContext);
if (bitmapData)
    free(bitmapData);
CGImageRelease(myImage);
}
```

and *myBitmapContext* is the context of the bitmap picture generated by the following function.

```
- (CGContextRef) MyCreateBitmapContext: (NSInteger) pixelsWide andPixelsHigh: (NSInteger) pixelsHigh{
CGContextRef    context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
NSInteger *          bitmapData;
NSInteger            bitmapByteCount;
NSInteger            bitmapBytesPerRow;

bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
bitmapData = (NSInteger *)calloc( bitmapByteCount, sizeof(uint8_t) );
if (bitmapData == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
if (context== NULL)
{
    free (bitmapData);
    return NULL;
}
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

return context;
}
```

I think there's nothing wrong with my code but I just can't draw the bitmap figure I want.

Comment: A picture is just a set of data. If you can get the data representing a picture, creating an image is trivial. What part of this puzzle are you having trouble with? Your question is lacking any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly realized that I made a very stupid mistake. The function `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()` has its return value, which is actually a `UIImage`. So the solution to this problem is just to assign the return value to `myView.image` to show the image.

Answer (score 0):

How about `UIImage(data: imageData)` in swift or `[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]` in Objective-C